# Homework Help with Node Voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image][image]

Hello, I just need a little guidance on if I am analyzing this circuit correctly using Node Voltage.

- Mesh and Thevenin Theorem resulted in Vy= 36V
- If i leave the ground where it is, the node after the 2A current source would be Vy.
- If i do KCL at the node where the 9A is, I get -(Vy/4)+9=0 thus, Vy=36V

I just want to make sure that I am allowed to do that instead of working with the dependent source and the super node.

Thank you!!

Comment: What you are "allowed to do" depends on the person who will be grading your work. However, if two nodes are connected by an ideal wire then they must have the same voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson so when doing Node analysis, the node between the voltage source and the resistor is -4Ix. The node above the 12 ohm resistor is Vy resulting in the node to the right of the 2A current source also being Vy? I just want to make sure that is clear for me. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: You are not quite right. Vy is not the voltage on **any** node, it is the voltage across the 12 ohm resistor. If you want to do nodal analysis, I **strongly** suggest that you name the nodes and then write the equations for your named nodes.

Answer (score 3):

### Restatement

I usually like to redraw schematics before attempting to analyze them. Some simplifications can arrive. Even if you are not *allowed* to use those simplifications directly in the answer, you can certainly use them to simplify cross-checking your results.

Here's your diagram as I see it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMaiPn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've inserted \$V_1\$ so as to make it clear what the CCVS operates on: \$I_{\text{V}_1}\$.

> The direction of the current I used for \$I_{\text{V}_1}\$ has various
> conventions. It really doesn't matter which convention you choose,
> though. Everything still works.
>
> For some, they want anything that consumes power to compute out as a
> positive value and anything that generates power to compute out as a
> negative value. In that case, my direction would be considered
> *wrong*!
>
> For others, like me, it's more *comforting* to imagine the direction
> to be consistent with the direction you might choose for a simple
> series loop in mesh analysis with a voltage source and a resistor, for
> example.
>
> I'm sticking by my convention. But you can use whatever you prefer, too.

### Easy Simplification

A simplification that pops to mind is that \$R_3\$ is completely irrelevant and can be shorted out. Current sources have infinite impedance, so \$R_3\$ washes out completely. You have no interest in, nor need to know, the voltage at node **d**. When setting up the nodal equation for node **a**, all you need to know is that there will be \$9\:\text{A}\$ arriving from that branch. End of story.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6qQC8.png)</sup>

### Nodal Equation Consideration

Just set up a nodal equation for node **a**, another nodal equation for node **b**, and then add \$V_a=V_b\$ as your third equation. You will be solving for three "unknowns." (Technically, anyway.) These are \$V_a\$, \$V_b\$, and \$I_{\text{V}_1}\$. (Of course, you should expect the solution to produce the same value for \$V_a\$ as for \$V_b\$.)

You really don't need to bother with node **c** because it is synonymous with the equation for the CCVS: \$4\cdot I_{\text{V}_1}\$.

(Or, put another way, by treating the voltage at node **c** as \$4\cdot I_{\text{V}_1}\$ you effectively cut away the CCVS from the schematic. It's no longer needed.)

So, when writing out the nodal equation for node **a**, you just substitute that equation in where you would normally place voltage or voltage difference (depending on how you like to write out your nodal equations.)

With those solutions in hand, it's very easy to work out \$V_y\$, as you know that you have \$9\:\text{A}\$ arriving into node **a** and \$I_{\text{V}_1}\$ leaving node **a**. The remainder must be supplied by \$R_1\$. So it is trivial to get. Just multiply \$R_1\$ by the remainder current. Done.

---

If you need more help than that, let me know. But hopefully that will move you forward.

---

### Nodal Equations

Nodal analysis is really easy if you just arrange your equations so that inflowing and outflowing currents are separated by the equal sign. It's almost impossible to mess it up, then.

Before I dive in, please note that I modified the above schematics to show my own personal choice for the ***direction*** of \$I_{\text{V}_1}\$. The equations below will be consistent to my preference. This may not be yours.

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{r}
  {\text{Node } a:}\vphantom{\frac{V_a}{R_1}}\\\\
  {\text{Node } b:}\vphantom{\frac{V_b}{R_2}}\\\\
  {\text{Assignment}:}\vphantom{V_b}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
      \frac{V_a}{R_1=12\:\Omega} + I_{V_{1}}\\\\
      \frac{V_b}{R_2=4\:\Omega}\\\\
      V_a
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_a}{R_1}}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{V_b}{R_2}}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{V_b}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      \left(I_1=9\:\text{A}\right)+\frac{V_c\,=\left(4\:\Omega\,\cdot\, I_{\text{V}_1}\right)}{R_1=12\:\Omega}\\\\
      \left(I_2=2\:\text{A}\right)+I_{\text{V}_1}\\\\
      V_b
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

(See [KCL Addendum](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/519982/38098).)

### Simultaneous Solution

Then just use [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
var('va vb iv1 i1 i2 r1 r2')
eqa = Eq( va/r1 + iv1, i1 + (4*iv1)/r1 )
eqb = Eq( vb/4, i2 + iv1 )
eq0 = Eq( va, vb )
ans = solve( [ eqa, eqb, eq0 ], [ va, vb, iv1 ] )
for x in ans: x, ans[x].subs({ i1:9, i2:2, r1:12, r2:4 })
(va, 124/3)
(vb, 124/3)
(iv1, 25/3)
```

It's a good thing that \$V_a\$ has the same value as \$V_b\$! Otherwise, I'd know I'd screwed up somewhere. Having them be the same doesn't mean I'm safe. But at least it's some small comfort.

At this point, all you need to do is compute \$V_y=R_1\cdot\left(I_1-I_{\text{V}_1}\right)\$:

```
vy = ( r1*( i1 - ans[iv1] ) ).subs({ i1:9, i2:2, r1:12, r2:4 })
vy
8
```

### Summary

That's not \$36\:\text{V}\$ as your comment suggests. But let's say you wanted to verify your answer. Just follow the logic below:

If \$V_y=V_{R_1}= 36\:\text{V}\$, then \$I_{R_1}= \frac{36\:\text{V}}{12\:\Omega}=3\:\text{A}\$ *away from node **a***. Since there is \$9\:\text{A}\$ coming *into node **a***, then it follows that \$I_{\text{V}_1}=9\:\text{A}-3\:\text{A}=6\:\text{A}\$ *away from node **a*** and *into node **b***. Since there is also \$2\:\text{A}\$ coming *into node **b***, this means that the \$I_{R_2}=6\:\text{A}+2\:\text{A}=8\:\text{A}\$. This means that \$V_b=8\:\text{A}\cdot 4\:\Omega=32\:\text{V}\$. We know \$V_a=V_b\$ so \$V_a=32\:\text{V}\$, too. And this must mean that \$V_c=V_a-V_y=-4\:\text{V}\$. Since \$4\:\Omega\cdot I_{\text{V}_1}=-4\:\text{V}\$ so also it must be that \$ I_{\text{V}_1}=-1\:\text{A}\$. But this is a contradiction!

So that's a way of testing your answer.

---

Now let's test sympy. (Hopefully it's good because I use it a lot.)

If \$V_y=V_{R_1}= 8\:\text{V}\$, then \$I_{R_1}= \frac{8\:\text{V}}{12\:\Omega}=\frac23\:\text{A}\$ *away from node **a***. Since there is \$9\:\text{A}\$ coming *into node **a***, then it follows that \$I_{\text{V}_1}=9\:\text{A}-\frac23\:\text{A}=8\frac13\:\text{A}\$ *away from node **a*** and *into node **b***. Since there is also \$2\:\text{A}\$ coming *into node **b***, this means that the \$I_{R_2}=8\frac13\:\text{A}+2\:\text{A}=10\frac13\:\text{A}\$. This means that \$V_b=10\frac13\:\text{A}\cdot 4\:\Omega=41\frac13\:\text{V}\$. We know \$V_a=V_b\$ so \$V_a=41\frac13\:\text{V}\$, too. And this must mean that \$V_c=V_a-V_y=33\frac13\:\text{V}\$. Since \$4\:\Omega\cdot I_{\text{V}_1}=33\frac13\:\text{V}\$ so also it must be that \$ I_{\text{V}_1}=8\frac13\:\text{A}\$. No contradiction!

Sympy didn't let me down. Good thing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I am getting stuck with what to write for the V1=0v. My 3 equations at the moment are as follows: Vb-Va=0 ,  (Vb/4)+Iv1=2   ,((Va+4Iv1)/12)+Iv1=9.    I would post a picture of my work but i am not familiar how to post pictures in the comment section.

Comment: @Etlewisg I'll get a chance to reply in two hours. Busy until then and reading your equations while on the road is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Etlewisg Well, I don't agree with your (Vb/4)+Iv1=2. But this just points up a very common problem with nodal analysis ***as it is usually taught***. I've an easier method, I believe. Put all the out-flowing currents on one side and all of the in-flowing currents on the other side. They must equal each other. Do you already know \$V_y\$ from the other methods?

Comment: @Etlewisg So far as I know, you cannot directly post pictures in the comments. You can write up a link that uses a description and an http reference in the format of \[description\]\(url\). However, you can post pictures in your question. Why not edit it and add a picture there?

Comment: Yes, I have gotten Vy=36V from using Mesh and Thevenin. I will update the post to include my work at this stage. @jonk

Comment: @Etlewisg Thanks so much for that. Then I will also post mine. You can compare them.

Comment: Thank you so very much for such a detailed response. You're method on separating the current by flowing in or out is way simpler to see and easier to setup the equations. I understand where i was going wrong and will work on studying some more as well as continue to practice drawing the circuits like you have. As of now my university has not shown us that way of drawing circuits yet, even though you are just separating the nodes that connect to the ground. Thank you once again!!! @jonk

Comment: @Etlewisg Thanks so much for your kind words. It makes all this worth it. I'm also glad to hear that you agree with me about setting up nodal equations. The method I showed you here is the same one used in Spice code. I think it is much more intuitive and it's nearly impossible to get the signs wrong. It just flows out from the mind so easily. Also, if you feel this answers your question, it's appropriate to select the answer (check it off as such.) This is not because you are rewarding me (or yourself) with this silly point system here. But it does save the time of others.