# How to solve this problem using supermesh analysis

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, mesh-analysis

Can we solve this problem using supermesh analysis? I thought you needed to have a common current source between each mesh? Is there an easier solution to this problem?
[image]

Comment: Yes, there is a simpler solution. For example, we can calculate that the Vp voltage is equal to \$V_P =  \frac{1V}{50\Omega + 1k\Omega} \times 1k\Omega\approx 0.9524V\$ Thus, the VCCS (voltage controlled current source) current is equal to \$I = 0.9524V \times 40S =38.1A \$ Now finding the output voltage is a trivial thing \$V_O = - 5k\Omega \times38.1A \times\frac{50k\Omega}{100\Omega +5k\Omega+50k\Omega} = -173.75kV \$. But for sure, you can use a mesh analysis too if you want.

Comment: Vp is a voltage drop across the 1k ohms resistor. Thus we need to know the current that will flow via 1k ohms resistor. And this current is equal to 1V/ (50 ohms + 1k ohms)  do you see it?

Comment: Did you manage to write and solve the circuit using the mesh analysis?

Comment: Honestly, not really I've been scratching my head on this all day. I even went back and read two previous chapters to have a better understanding of the fundamentals. I've been trying to create a super mesh on I_1 and I_2 by combing those. But I am still having no luck

Comment: can you write the mesh equation for loop \$I_2\$ base on my loop?

Comment: Because  we know the \$I_1\$ mash current value 
$$I_1 = 40S \times V_P = 40S \times  I_L \times 1k\Omega $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

One loop on the left side:

$$ -1V + I_L\:50\Omega + I_L\:1k\Omega = 0$$ (1)

And two loops on the right side \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$.

And for \$I_2\$ loop we can write mesh equation like this:

$$ I_2\: 5k\Omega + I_2\:100\Omega (I_2 + I_1)50k\Omega = 0$$ (2)

For the \$I_1\$ loop we do not need to write a mesh equation because we have a current source in it hence, the \$I_1\$ mesh current must be equal to VCCS current.

$$I_1 = 40S \times V_P $$

Additional we know that:

$$V_P = I_L \times 1k\Omega $$

And finally, we have:

$$I_1 = 40S \times V_P  = 40S \times \:I_L \times 1k\Omega $$

Now we can substitute this into equation 2 thus we end up with this two eqiations:

$$ -1V + I_L\:50\Omega + I_L\:1k\Omega = 0$$
$$I_2\: 5k\Omega + I_2\:100\Omega (I_2 + \left(40S\:I_L\:1k\Omega )\right)50k\Omega = 0$$

And the solution is:

$$I_L = 0.952mA$$
$$I_2 = - 34.569A$$

And from the Ohm's law we have

$$V_O = I_L \times 5k\Omega =- 34.569A \times 5k\Omega = -172.845kV $$

Comment: @GenoC No wrong. I thought that you know how to write the mesh equations. Try to read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392631/mesh-current-polarity-equation-setup/392636#392636 Is this any help?

Answer (score 2):

### Mesh Solution

Mesh analysis entails identifying each of the loops in a circuit and the voltage drops in those loops per Kirchoff's Voltage Law. A single current flows in the loop, and relates to the voltage drops of interest by Ohm's Law. Notice that a current (and therefore current source) is not required to use KVL, it is just related to KVL by Ohm's Law.

Here, it is easy to identify the loop on the left. There are also two independent loops on the right, which may be combined to make the right side into a supermesh loop; 'super' generally indicates that two smaller parts are combined into a larger one. Then, the Voltage-Controlled Voltage Source relates the two loops.

Let me know if I have clarified what is meant by mesh and supermesh analysis, and I will return to this in a short while when I have time to show what I mean with a solution to the problem using mesh analysis.

### Simpler Calculations

As for whether this is easier, I think that mesh analysis is very close to circuit fundamentals and is easy to understand. In terms of calculation efficiency, it is fastest to recognise the left loop as a voltage divider, combine the series resistors in the right loop, use current divider equations, then Ohm's Law on the resistor across the output to obtain the voltage. I will show this with a second solution.

Voltage divider:
\$V_P=1000/(1000+50)\$

Current divider:
\$I_o=40V_P*50000/(50000+5100)=40(1000/1050)(50000/55100)=34.569A\$

\$V_o=-I_o*R=-34.569*5000=-172.8kV\$

*note the negative polarity of the voltage due to the direction of the current through the output resistor*

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present another method of solving your problem. This will be another way of [@G36](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/92635/g36) did it, I will use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to do it.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Bkct.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_1+\text{I}_0\\
\\
\text{I}_0=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_1+\text{I}_4\\
\\
0=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_7
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, it is not hard to solve for \$\text{V}_2\$ when \$\displaystyle\lim_{\text{R}_3\to\infty}\$ using your values:

$$\text{V}_2=-\frac{2000000000}{11571}\approx-172845.9078731311\space\text{V}\tag3$$

Where I used Mathematica-code to solve for that:

```
In[1]:=Vi = 1;
R1 = 50;
R2 = 1*1000;
R4 = 50*1000;
R5 = 100;
R6 = 5*1000;
n = 40;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I3 == n*V1 + I0, I0 == I4 + I6, 
   I5 == n*V1 + I4, 0 == I5 + I6 + I7, I2 == I1 + I7, 
   I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/Infinity, 
   I4 == (V2 - V3)/R4, I5 == V3/R5, I6 == V2/R6}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4,
    I5, I6, I7, V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> -(800/21), I1 -> 1/1050, I2 -> 1/1050, I3 -> 0, 
  I4 -> -(13600/3857), I5 -> 400000/11571, I6 -> -(400000/11571), 
  I7 -> 0, V1 -> 20/21, V2 -> -(2000000000/11571), 
  V3 -> 40000000/11571}}

In[2]:=N[%1,16]

Out[2]={{I0 -> -38.09523809523810, I1 -> 0.0009523809523809524, 
  I2 -> 0.0009523809523809524, I3 -> 0, I4 -> -3.526056520611875, 
  I5 -> 34.56918157462622, I6 -> -34.56918157462622, I7 -> 0, 
  V1 -> 0.9523809523809524, V2 -> -172845.9078731311, 
  V3 -> 3456.918157462622}}
```